# Uncaught Error: No module: users Angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

this is a follow up question of this [How to fetch index data in Angular using rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312689/how-to-fetch-index-data-in-angular-using-rails-server)

**Question**
How to correctly upload / link angular module with html ?

Following the accepted answer and updating the code, I can not load module users:

```
Uncaught Error: No module: users
```

Gist from my project is [here](https://gist.github.com/maro10/6268778)

updated code:

```
app.factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource "users/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
    index:   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
    show:    { method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' },
    update:  { method: 'PUT', responseType: 'json' }
  }
})

var UsersIndexCtrl = function($scope, User) {
  $scope.users = User.index();
};
```

updated plunker according to the accepted answer is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NovQxb0a7013GQDFgsvk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors with the following

```
return $resource "users/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
    ...
}
```

Should be

```
return $resource("users/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
    ...
});
```