# TypeError: object is not a function - fetching collection data using Angular / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, error-handling, typeahead

ok this is the last question from todays trilogy of learning Angular:

[part1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312689/how-to-fetch-index-data-in-angular-using-rails-server)

[part2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314258/uncaught-error-no-module-users-angularjs)

I am getting to following error(when trying to select user in view:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.source (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6300:13)
    at getMatchesAsync (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-bootstrap.js?body=1:1820:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-bootstrap.js?body=1:1871:13
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12030:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:134:11)
    at $setViewValue (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12029:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:11423:14
    at Object.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:7994:28)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8074:23) angular.js?body=1:5688
(anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:5688
(anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:4785
Scope.$apply angular.js?body=1:8076
listener angular.js?body=1:11422
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:5096
elemData.handle
```

with this code (updated according to the SO answers:

```
  <div ng-app='users'>

    <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="UsersIndexCtrl">
      <pre>Model: {{result | json}}</pre>
      <input type="text" ng-model="result" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in users($viewValue)">
    </div>


<script>


    var app = angular.module('users', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);

    app.factory('User', function($resource) {
        return $resource("users/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
            index:   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
            show:    { method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' },
            update:  { method: 'PUT', responseType: 'json' }
        });
    })


    var UsersIndexCtrl = function($scope, User) {
        $scope.users = User.index();
    };


</script>
```

I am trying to fetch all users from the server using typeahead.

Latest version of plunker code is  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NovQxb0a7013GQDFgsvk)

**Questions:**
1. How to fetch collection data from server and make typeahead running using angular and modifying this code ?.
2. What does this error means and how it is causes in connection to this code.

Comment: $scope.users is an array and you are calling it as a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not with your `index` function, but in your `typeahead` directive usage.  This is what you want (assuming you want to search by the `name` property on your `User` resource:

```
<div ng-app='users'>
  <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="UsersIndexCtrl">
    <pre>Model: {{result | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="result" typeahead="user.name for user in users | filter:$viewValue">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've edited your [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yN8gdTVDkvfYGlxXhXbb) so that your example works :)